# How can I control visibility of MTDs in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am working on a board running Linux, and which has two NOR-flash devices.
They are described in the device tree so that a bunch of MTDs show up under /dev/.

But, I would like to hide the MTDs from one of the NOR-flash devices until they are actually needed (during upgrades).

I have found that I can unbind the driver from the NOR-flash after booting, then rebind when needed.
However, I would prefer if the system could boot up without binding in the first place.
I've tried by editing the device tree and setting **status="disabled"** and by removing the **compatible** field, but both approaches apparently made it impossible to bind the driver to the NOR-flash. (There was no **driver_override** node.)

Is there some way I can get the system to let *me* decide when to bind the driver or to show the MTDs?

Answer (score 0):

The `compatible` attribute associates the driver to the device (the NOR flash controller), and the `status` affects the device.
It makes sense that what you tried didn't achieve the desired result.
If the MTD partition definitions are in the DT, then why can't you simply comment out the partitions you do not want visible?

> Is there some way I can get the system to let me decide when to bind the driver?

Yes, that is what the Device Tree is capable of.
But for your situation, you should be dealing with the partitions, not the device (since there are two chips attached to the one controller)!
See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mtd/partition.txt
If the MTD partition is not defined, then a device node obviously cannot be created for it in **/dev**.

Comment: You're right that it is the actual MTD partitions that I'd like to hide away. But it is not clear to me how I can make the MTDs show up later, when we start an upgrade. Sorry if it did not come across clearly that this is what I want.

Comment: You boot the kernel with the MTD partitions that you want exposed.  The MTD partitions can be defined either in the Device Tree or through the kernel command line.  For an upgrade to use the second chip, a new DT blob (with the expanded MTD partition definitions) would have to be first installed, the system rebooted, and then the upgrade can continue.  Depending on the kernel version that you're using, there could be dynamic MTD partitioning, but that also requires at least the master MTD device (i.e. the second NOR flash chip) to already exist.